# Twitter offline access in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, twitter, offline

I'm doing a project where post on Twitter, Facebook, Flickr should be done offline.

Is there any way to do this in rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is in the Episode 7 of Gemaweek screencast at http://gemaweek.com/

Comment: Hi That video is for online users. But i need offline access to post on the user wall, when the user is offline.

Comment: It does work offline too. You got to store the access token of the user, then using that access token, you can do post in their wall.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.